# Error opening conn with System.Data.SQLite, An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Interop.084

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to set up a DB connection using System.Data.SQLite. I'm using the Compact Framework binaries version 1.0.84. and windows Vista and .net 3.5

I'm working with SharpDevelop. I saw a couple other posts that dealt with this issue, but I think those turned out to be 32bit vs 64bit issues that were resolved by modifying the project properties in some form of Visual Studio, which I'm not using. Also I checked the project properties in my IDE and all options I can see point to x86 and 32 bit. I also tried using "Any CPU" in the properties with no luck.

Here's the relevant code:

```
try{

 SQLiteConnection conn;

 conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\my path");

 conn.Open();
 conn.Close();
}
catch (SQLiteException ex){
   throw new Exception(ex.Message);

}
```

And here's the exception I get when running in debug:
I replaced my local paths.

```
System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
in System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open
in System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open
in mypath 
in System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick
in System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick
in System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp
in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp
in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc
in System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc
in System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc
in ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage
in ControlNativeWindow.WndProc
in System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback
in         ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafenativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop
in ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner
in ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop
in System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run
in mypath
```

Also, when I add SQLite.Interop.084.dll as a reference I get a warning about bad image file or no metadata. The "local copy" option is grayed out in the properties.

I replaced the DLL for an older version (1.0.66) and now I'm getting "MSB3247 - Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly"

I deleted everything in my project folders and started from scratch but I keep on getting stuck. Has anybody successfully implemented a solution for the Compact Framework? Can anybody suggest a similar database manager that can be used in a pocket pc?

- I returned to version 1.0.84 after hours struggling with version 1.0.66. Now I'm getting this message:  Can't load file SQLite3.cs under c:\dev\sqlite\dotnet\System.Data.SQLite.

That path must be from the machine where they developed the dll so I'm guessing there's something wrong with the adapter. I think I'd rather try with a different database software now so I guess at this point I'll take suggestions on that end rather than solutions.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't add SQLite.Interop.084.dll as reference but be sure to use the correct version (x86 vs x64). I'm pretty sure the problem is related with a wrong dll version.

Comment: I've only found 1 download for Compact Framework at the System.Data.SQLite website: 
sqlite-netFx35-binary-PocketPC-2008-1.0.84.0.zip
 That only contains SQLite.Interop.084.dll and another System.Data.SQLite.dll. Do I need to manually add Interop to one of my project folders?

Comment: Try copying the dll manually to the build output folder but according the error it seems it's already there.

Comment: I removed the Interop dll from the project references, then copied it to the debug folders. Do I also need the .pdb file? I removed it because it seemed to point to a path in the machine they used to develop it.

Am I using the right type of Exception object? Is there some other type that provides more information?

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm in a 32 bit Windows Vista, but I'm planning on developing for a Pocket PC, so I'm using Compact Framework.
The profile for my project is targeting Compact Framework and I downloaded the Precompiled Binaries for Windows CE (.NET Compact Framework 3.5) from here: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Again, I would really appreciate any help in making this work

Comment: Sorry, I kind of missed the "Compact Framework" part. Don't want to throw random answers so I'd continue researching if "dll"-"buil configuration" mismatch could be the problem.

Comment: I'm thinking there's a problem with the Interop dll. Maybe it was developed for 64 bit?
If I remove it from the build folder, it throws an exception saying it can't find Interop. If I include it it throws the same BadImage exception

Now I tried an older version (1.0.66) of System.Data.SQLite and now I'm getting a conflicting assembly versions exception. I already deleted everything in my projects folders and started from scratch, so I have no clue what this new DLL is actually conflicting with.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I tried the "regular" Windows version and it worked on the first try. I did nothing different. Unfortunately I need to develop for a Pocket PC so I'm still screwed

I guess the binaries for the Compact Framework have some kind of flaw, and C#'s vague exceptions weren't very helpful either. I suppose the binaries were developed for a 64 bit machine and just left that way.

So basically, **using System.Data.SQLite for Windows Compact Framework, either version 1.0.66 or 1.0.84 can't be done. At least out of the box.** I'm gonna look for another version and see what comes up.

*I know that this post hasn't gotten "many" replies, but if I was looking for this info, I would like to find something relevant, so I'll just leave it here.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I tried to do the same thing and I have a project where I implemented this

[image]

The solution was to uncheck the prefer-32-bit box and use the "x86 platform" target, even though this will use the double resource for downloading.